# Choice between nested enum or nested class/struct

Tags: c#, enums

If I need a class object to have a certain property, let's call it "**type**".

I want type to be either **"wheeled"** or **"nonWheeled".** If the instance of the vehicle class is set to have the property wheeled, I want that property to also have one of two other properties, such as **"twoWheeled"** or **"fourWheeled".**

I tried doing this using enums such as:

```
private enum wheeledTypes {
    twoWheeled,
    fourWheeled
}

private enum Wheels
{
    a = wheeledTypes.twoWheeled,
    b = wheeledTypes.fourWheeled,
    c = nonWheeled
}
```

But as you can see, then I get three types (a/b/c, which I don't want). I only want a/b, or wheeled/nonWheeled, where wheeled in turn can be of two types.

Edit: If classes were used, you would expect them to have properties, constructors, methods, etc, themselves. I don't want this. I just want to set the vehicle to be either a wheeled (two/four) , or a nonWheeled. Wheeled and nonWheeled should not have further properties. That is why I assumed enums would be appropriate. Maybe I am wrong!

Comment: Why don't you use inheritance?

Answer (score 1):

You should be making classes, like this:

```
class Vehicle { }

class NonWheeledVehicle : Vehicle { }

class WheeledVehicle : Vehicle 
{ 
    internal enum WheelTypes { TwoWheeled, FourWheeled }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't you have a base `Vehicle` and a child `WheeledVehicle` with an enum `WheelType`? Where's the non-wheeled vehicle here?

Comment: Wouldn't the base class be "Vehicle" & 3 derived classes - "NonWheeledVehicle" in addition to your two.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto -- I guess I read the question a bit too quickly.

Comment: But the thing is, when you defined classes, you expect them to have properties, constructors, methods, etc, themselves. I don't want this. I just want to set the vehicle to be either a wheeled (two/four) , or a nonWheeled. Wheeled and nonWheeled should not have further properties.

Comment: @StephenJohnson -- No that's not true at all.  Classes can be as simple as empty types, as I've shown.  They're just tools, and they are flexible and extensible.  Once you embrace that idea and use it over and over in practice, you'll become more comfortable with it.

Comment: Ok, thank's. Ill try it and let you know when I have confirmed you are right.

Answer (score 0):

You would want something like this:

```
public enum WheelType
{
    TwoWeeled,
    FourWeeled
}

public class Vehicle
{

}

public class WheeledVehicle : Vehicle
{
    public WheelType WheelType { get; set; }
}
```

Then, `Vehicle` is your `non-wheeled` vehicle type, and `WheeledVehicle` is your `Vehicle` that has a specific `WheelType`.

Answer (score 0):

Use classes instead

```
class Vehicle {
}

class Wheeled : Vehicle {
}

class NonWheeled : Vehicle {
}

class TwoWheeled : Wheeled {
}

class FourWheeled: Wheeled {
}
```

Comment: How does this give you only `Wheeled` and `Non-Wheeled` types?

Comment: Using type of so if vehicle.GetType() == typeof(Wheeled) than it's wheels vehicle same goes underneath if wheeled.GetType() == typeof(TwoWheeled) it's 2 wheel

Comment: He wants **two** types, not **three**

Comment: I am only giving him a suggestion not a final code. This is a one way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Enums are not used as properties but only as representation of constant values such as integers, strings e.t.c

What you want is applicable through inheritance.

```
// abstract if you do not want a vehicle to exist with having a concrete definition
public abstract class Vehicle {
}

public class NonWheeled : Vehicle{
}

public abstract class WheeledVehicle : Vehicle {
}

public class TwoWheeledVehicle : WheeledVehicle {
}

public class FourWheeledVehicle : WheeledVehicle {
}

public class ThousandWheeledVehicle : WheeledVehicle {
}
```

Or depending on your need you could keep the number of wheels as an enum as @rory.ap suggested

Comment: How does this give you only `Wheeled` and `Non-Wheeled` types?

Comment: True. Added more abstraction

Comment: The OP is looking to have **2** types: wheeled and non-wheeled, where wheeled may be of 2 or 4 wheels. You are giving him **4** different types.

Comment: OP had a completely wrong understanding of enums. You are also right hence i also pointed out to @rory.ap 's answer

Answer (score 0):

Just a suggestion, but why not simply make the property nullable? That way if it's null, it's non-wheeled and you can still do direct comparisons to the enumeration

```
enum Wheels{
    twoWheeled,
    fourWheeled
}

class AnyClass
{
    public Wheels? Wheels{get;set;} //the question marks makes the property nullable
}

var a=  new AnyClass{Wheels = Wheels.twoWheeled};
if(a.Wheels == null){} //unwheeled
if(a.Wheels.HasValue){} //wheeled
if(a.Wheels==Wheels.twoWheeled){} //direct check on specific type also works
```

Personally I also like to add an interface exposing the property. That way you can make extension methods on that interface, such as `static bool HasWheels(this IWheels wheelsObject)`